# Custom Order Status for Cancel not working

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, sales-order, order-status

I have the following observer method thats been called successfully, but the order status is not changing.

```
public function customCancel(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getPayment()->getOrder();
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getId());
        $payment_code = $observer->getEvent()->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
        if ($payment_code == 'cashondelivery') {
            $order->setStatus("cod_cancel");
            $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true, 'Cancel Transaction.');
            Mage::log($payment_code, null, 'paymentMethod.log');
            $order->save();
        }
    }
```

I have implemented the following event.

> sales_order_payment_cancel

Comment: Please add the `magento-1` tag here

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot more going on canceling an order than just simply set its state to `canceled`. Please try following code sections inside your if-block instead and see if at least one of them gets you there:

```
$order->registerCancellation('Cancel Transaction.', false);
```

`false` will throw an exception if the order is not subject to cancelation.

If this doesn't work for you, try

```
$order->cancel();
```

This one might cause trouble since it cancels the payment, too, to which your observer is listening so you might create an infinite loop. Maybe there's an event better suited for your situation.

Comment: Not working either of these options